# module 'mmcv' has no attribute '__version__

Tags: face-detection

I'm trying to use mmdet and mmcv in SCRFD for face detection and face this error:

```
 mmcv_version = digit_version(mmcv.__version__)
 AttributeError: module 'mmcv' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Has any buddy hit this error before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

for torch 1.8 :

```
pip3 install mmcv-full==1.3.15 -f https://download.openmmlab.com/mmcv/dist/cu111/torch1.8.0/index.html
```

this command worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For CPU Version :

```
pip3 install mmcv-full==1.3.17 -f https://download.openmmlab.com/mmcv/dist/cpu/torch1.8.0/index.html
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

For those having this issue with torch>=2.0.0 the mmcv code has changed as described here: [mmcv v2 changes to API reference](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmcv/blob/2e44eaeba36b3f4c304e830053fc2660d8407afb/docs/en/get_started/api_reference.md#L164)

Therefore you'll need to use that table to  look up any classes or functions you are importing. For each you will need to replace them with the corresponding new code.
E.g.

```
from mmcv.fileio.file_client import BaseStorageBackend
```

Becomes:

```
from mmengine.fileio.backends.base import BaseStorageBackend
```

Comment: Can you provide here the "*as described here*" details? Also, please clarify what "*you'll need to alter any mmcv imports to match that new version.*" means exactly (give an example).